# Silverlight open source font replacement for Segoe

Tags: silverlight, font-face

I'm currently building a LOB application in Silverlight 4. I've been considering the question of typography for the application.

After some experimentation on the design side the font that people like is Segoe UI. Now I can embed this font and although the font is freely available in Windows we don’t have distribution rights for this font.

I am looking for an open source font visually equivalent of the Segoe family that can be freely distributed.

Does such a font exist?

Comment: Fontography is an important part of the presentation for any software product. Microsoft are aware of this, just look at the fonts used in Windows Mobile 7 app (another Segoe font derivative).

I have found a distributable font pack for XNA, which can be found here:
http://creators.xna.com/en-GB/contentpack/fontpack

Just need one for SL4 now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best answer that I have found is demonstrated in Microsoft's sample themes for Silverlight (can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e9da0eb8-f31b-4490-85b8-92c2f807df9e&displaylang=en)).

Essentially you specify the set of fonts you'd like in descending order ensuring that there is an available font on all target platforms (ie. Segoe UI probably won't be on a Mac or a Windows XP box).

```
<FontFamily x:Key="DefaultFontFamily">Segoe UI, Lucida Sans Unicode, Verdana</FontFamily>

<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource DefaultFontFamily}"/>
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Google Web Fonts has a font called Open Sans which is very very close to Segoe UI:

http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans